# Anychart Packing Chart

Tags: next.js, anychart

everyone.
I need to your help to implementing bubble chart using anychart.

I am now using AnyChart’s Circle Packing chart to implement the bubble chart. The chart is almost done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gyR9.png)

I am going to put the whitespace between all the circles at all.
But unfortunately, I don't find the solution now.

I would be appreciated it if you let me know how to implement it.
Thanks.